# pomegranate could not be found on class path

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to do a tutorial about Castra and Hoplon and am trying to follow the basic steps to set it up.  The project uses https://github.com/tailrecursion/boot to bootstrap itself, and I can't get it to work at all.  I cloned the repo and built it (boot, that is), and get the following error when I try to use it to do anything (start the tutorial or do the hello world app thingy from boots github readme):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cemerick/pomegranate__init.class
or cemerick/pomegranate.clj on classpath: 

at clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:411)
clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke (core.clj:5530)
clojure.core$load.doInvoke (core.clj:5529)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
.......
```

I am very new to clojure in general but after googling around I don't know what to do.  It seems kind of ironic also as the whole point of Pomegranate is to put things on your class path and the error is that *it* isn't on class path.

Comment: What exactly are you doing to launch it?

Comment: Just like in the readme made the file build.boot and then run boot build.boot.  Boot is obviously on the path, it finds it and tries to start and dies as soon as it get to that pomegranate line.

Comment: I notice there is no project.clj file in either of the things I am trying to boot, going to try making one.  But nothing mentions that it needs that.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `build.boot` file check if your line 3 is:

`#tailrecursion.boot.core/version "2.3.1"`

And if you have boot.task 2.1.2 in your deps

[tailrecursion/boot.task   "2.1.2"]

HTH

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to update the code: https://github.com/mathias/gleam/pull/2